# P&T Assets - How to show no results?

Tags: assets, conditionals, module, no-results

i was playing around with Assets 2.1.4 and i was wondering if there is any way of checking for no results.

My code:

```
{my_assets_field limit="30" offset="80"}
    <li><a href="{url}" alt="{alt_text}">{filename}</a></li>
{/my_assets_field}
```

Example of what i have in mind:

```
{my_assets_field limit="30" offset="80"}
    {if no_results} the end{/if}
    <li><a href="{url}" alt="{alt_text}">{filename}</a></li>
{/my_assets_field}
```

I'm doing a ajax call to this template and i need to know when i reach the end.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
{if my_assets_field}
{my_assets_field limit="30" offset="80"}
    <li><a href="{url}" alt="{alt_text}">{filename}</a></li>
{/my_assets_field}
{if:else}
the end
{/if}
```

But I don't know if this solution works for what you need with your ajax call.

Comment: The ajax call returned blank if no results so this was my "fix" with the javascript response.


`data = $.trim(data);
    if(data==""){
     // end
    }
` 
I'm going to try what you did there.

Thanx for the response!